# MATLAB change repeating timer period

Tags: matlab, timer

**Is it possible to change the Period of a repeating timer (in TimerFcn)?**

Intuitively, when programming for Windows, I would handle WM_TIMER messages and use SetTimer to edit the period of a timer, but a similar approach doesn't seem to work in MATLAB, because the timer needs to be restarted in order to change the Period property. This messes up execution, which can be best described as changing the period to near-zero. No errors are produced.

Here's some example code that's used to create a task array: each task item consists of something to do and a delay. The array is basically walked by a timer, which should change its Period based on the current task delay.

```
function obj = Scheduler(~)
    obj.scheduletimer = timer(...
        'TimerFcn',@obj.OnTimer,...
        'BusyMode','queue',...
        'TasksToExecute',length(obj.tasklist),...
        'ExecutionMode','fixedRate');
end
function OnTimer(obj,source,event)
    obj.Start(); // Executed task, schedule next
end
function Start(obj)

    // Stop timer if needed
    if(strcmp(obj.scheduletimer.Running,'on'))
        stop(obj.scheduletimer);
    end;

    // Set new period and resume
    if(~isempty(obj.tasklist))
        obj.scheduletimer.Period = obj.tasklist(1).something;
        start(obj.scheduletimer);
    end;
end
```

When I don't mess with the timer in OnTimer, everything obviously works fine, but I'd like to change the Period each iteration.

Edit: I've tried to implement the pingpong solution suggested by Pursuit, but it's still not working. Note that the switching timers idea does work, but periods still don't seem to be applied.

```
function obj = Scheduler(~)
    obj.timer1 = timer(...
        'TimerFcn',@obj.OnTimer);
     obj.timer2 = timer(...
        'TimerFcn',@obj.OnTimer);
end
function OnTimer(obj,source,event)
    obj.Start(); // Executed task, schedule next
end
function Start(obj)
    if(strcmp(obj.timer1.Running,'on'))
        obj.timer2.Period = obj.tasklist{1}{2};
        start(obj.timer2);
    else
        obj.timer1.Period = obj.tasklist{1}{2};
        start(obj.timer1);
    end;
end
```

Ugh.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, but don't know how to fix it. The only solution I managed to get was to set the timer's mode to singleShot and use the StartDelay property to control how long before the callback fires. Then, in the callback, stop the timer and delete it, then create a new timer and start it. Suboptimal, but for some reason it doesn't want to work any other way.

Comment: fixed your comments. You may also be interested in the user-script for Matlab syntax highlighting on SO (see the Matlab tag info for the link)

Comment: @wakjah: I'm about to give up and switch to that method...

Comment: @wakjah: yep, using StartDelay in combination with timer recreation or ping pong seems to be the (only) solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I ended up using wakjah's solution. It's ugly as hell, but it worked. Matlab really should hav an option where 'Period' can be an array whose length matches the TasksToExecute property. Would make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two timers, (e.g. `timerNamePing` and `timerNamePong`).  At the end of the action for each timer setup the next timer to execute once in single shot mode with some delay.

This avoids the need to constantly tear down and create new timers, and avoids the error which occurs when you try and edit a timer which is currently executing.

Here is a working example to demonstrate:

```
function setupPingPong

timerPing = timer;
timerPong = timer;

timerPing.TimerFcn = @(~,~)pingPongActivity(true,  timerPing, timerPong);
timerPing.Name = 'PingTimer';

timerPong.TimerFcn = @(~,~)pingPongActivity(false, timerPing, timerPong);
timerPong.Name = 'PongTimer';

timerPing.StartDelay = 0;
start(timerPing);

function pingPongActivity(isPing, timerPing, timerPong)
    if isPing
        disp(['PING (' datestr(now,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF') ')'])
    else
        disp(['PONG (' datestr(now,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF') ')'])
    end
    delayTime = ceil(rand*10);
    display(['    delaying '  num2str(delayTime) ' sec.'])
    if isPing
        nextTimer = timerPong;
    else
        nextTimer = timerPing;
    end
    set(nextTimer,'StartDelay', delayTime);
    start(nextTimer);
```

Once this is going, to stop the madness, I use:

```
t = timerfind; stop(t); delete(t)
```

Comment: A reasonable approach, but I think error will accumulate due to the difference between scheduled due time and actual execution of the handler.

Comment: If it's really an issue you could do a tic / toc within the callback, and adjust the StartDelay of the next executing timer to compensate for the difference between the desired and actual time of the currently executing timer (and any past accumulated errors).

Comment: If absolute time accuracy is needed I would compute the offset to the next iteration based on the current value of `now`.  This would prevent error accumulation, although I still would not trust it to be very accurate.

Comment: @Pursuit: accuracy is not very important: an error of about 50ms is not a problem. And I've tried to implement your fix, but it's not working, yet.

Comment: Yep, using ping pong or timer recreation (see wakjah's comments) does the trick, basically because one cannot change Period of a running timer. This means StartDelay is the only configurable delay option. Ping pong and recreate seem to be equally fast though, so the in my opinion simpler recreate fix might be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I use the 'StopFcn' property in timer object again to restart the counter.

something like this ('TimerScale' changes the next period)

init :

```
Timer_OBJ = timer(  'ExecutionMode', 'singleShot', ...
                                    'StartDelay', SystemTicksSecs/TimerScale, ...
                                    'TimerFcn', @(src,evt)obj.TimerCallBack,...
                                    'StopFcn', @(src,evt)obj.TimerStopCallBack );

                start(Timer_OBJ);
```

and inside TimerStopCallBack

```
  set(Timer_OBJ, 'StartDelay', SystemTicksSecs/TimerScale);                

    start(Timer_OBJ);
```